# Reading Numbers until condition met

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to ask the user to keep typing in numbers until they type -1 once they do the code will say Thank you see you later! I'm kind of stuck right now cause my loop is infinite loop and I'm trying to solve it without using iterations. This is what I have.

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Type numbers: ");
int num = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());   
while (num < -1 || num > -1) {
    System.out.println(num);   
        if (num == -1) {
        System.out.println("Thank you and see you later!");
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your loop is infinite because you use the same `num` value entered initially. It never changes inside a loop and has no chance to change, understand?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Yeah I knew that was the problem, I just never knew you can put Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine()); by itself, I thought you had to assign it to a variable all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = 0;
System.out.println("Type numbers: ");
while(true){
    //get user input
    num = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    if(num == -1){
        System.out.println("Thank you and see you later!");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works but I want "Type Numbers: " to show only once in the output, I had this but I'm not suppose to have Type numbers showing up over and over

Comment: Just put "Type numbers:" before the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the input inside the loop. You're only doing it once (before entering the loop) so the value of num never changes.  Also, you could simplify your while condition by using `while (num != -1)`

So ultimately, you'd want something like this:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Type numbers: ");
int num = 0;
while (num != -1) {
    num = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());   

        if (num == -1) {
            System.out.println("Thank you and see you later!");

    }else{
       System.out.println(num);   
    }

}
```

Comment: if you break right after condition is met, no need to check it in `while()`

Comment: @Chris your code doesn't work, because everytime you put in a number it doesn't really go through the loop, and 0 is always printed after the number you put in because num = 0 and never changes

Comment: @Nabz, you're right. I made an edit to clean it up.